# How can I make a specific character the center point on a header?

Tags: node.js, client, ejs

For example, I have

team1 0-0 team2

Lets say team1 = "David" and team2 = "Bob"

then the center of the page would be

```
David 0-0 Bob
     ^
```

How do I make it so that the 0-0 is the centered at all times?
I do not want to use margins because the team names vary.
Also, trying to align items - center produces an uneven header.

I want the header to be read as a single line, not like
team1
0-0
team2.

```
<header id="header">
        <nav>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <a class="nav-brand miniHeader2">Current Score</a><br>
                    <a class="nav-brand text-gradient3" id="headerText">
                        Hamber <%=selectedMatch.ourScore %>-<%=selectedMatch.theirScore%> <%=selectedMatch.team %>
                    </a>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try grouping just the score inside its own inline element like `<span>`, and use **CSS Grid**:

```html
<a class="nav-brand text-gradient3" id="headerText">
  Hamber
  <span>
    <%=selectedMatch.ourScore %>&ndash;<%=selectedMatch.theirScore%>
  </span>
  <%=selectedMatch.team %>
</a>
```

---

```css
#headerText {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
  gap: 1ch; /* Optional */
  font-variant-numeric: tabular-nums; /* Optional */
}
```

- [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) specifies sizes for each column in the grid, the columns being elements or text fragments. Using the `1fr` [fractional unit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout/Basic_concepts_of_grid_layout#the_fr_unit) should ensure that both sides have an
  **equal width**.
- The `gap` will make sure there's always some space between the team names and the score, just like in your example, even if all the text doesn't fit into the parent container.
- As a bonus, the `font-variant-numeric` property will make each digit
  have the same width (if the font supports it), so as the score
  changes, it should stay in one place.

If you're going to be dealing with really long team names, try looking into [CSS text truncation](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/).